# My prefix lost a life, My suffix had a meal

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> My prefix lost a life.
>
> My suffix had a meal.
>
> My infix has a life.
>
> My whole is a big deal.

Hint:

> perseverance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Dedicate

My prefix lost a life.

> **Ded** sounds like "dead"

My suffix had a meal.

> **Ate**

My infix has a life.

> **Cat** (some say it has nine).

My whole is a big deal.

> To **dedicate** means to devote something, which is a big deal

Hint

> "perseverance" suggests dedication which is what lead me to this guess.

Comment: Well done for finding it, though it makes me sad the 'i' isn't clued at all...! :(

Comment: @Stiv, yes, me too, that was one of the main things that made me doubt this answer. I was tempted o go for "I, cat" for dramatic effect.